# My Quit Button is not playing the sound when i click it, except this all the button are playing sound. Can anyone solve this problem?

Tags: android, button, audio, click, media-player

//     This is my app exit button it destroys the activity and exits the user from an app. I want to //play a sound when I click this button but unfortunately, the sound is not playing and the activity //destroys. Please help me in solving this issue. Except for this button, all my button sound is working.

//   This is my second activity, in this activity, I have used a button for quitting the app but I also //want the button to play a sound when the button is clicked by user. But it is not playing the sound and //quits the app which destroys activity. please tell me how to play the sound on my exit button during //the click

```
      mExitApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit_app);

           final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample2);

            mExitApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mp.start();
    
                    ScoreActivity.this.finish();

                    System.exit(0);
    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to wait for the sound to end playing before finishing the activity/process.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.start();
                    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ScoreActivity.this.finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                      }
                    }, 300);
                }
```

A more cleaner solution would probably involve a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        finish(); // finish current activity
    }
});
```

Or you could play the sound in a foreground/background service. But then you shouldn't kill the entire process (`System.exit(0)`) like you do now ofc.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. The second one is the best solution for this.